# Prove that all positive integers $n$, $(1-{\sqrt 5})^n$ can be written in the form $a-b{\sqrt 5}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers

Tags: induction

Prove, by induction, that all positive integers $n$, $(1-{\sqrt 5})^n$ can be written in the form $a-b{\sqrt 5}$  where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

I understand these idea of proof by induction and this was a different type of question that I'm used too and wasn't sure on how to approach it as I'm not entirely confident with proving things with induction yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you mean with “all integers $n$, $\left(1-\sqrt5\right)$”?

Comment: yes sorry i will add that on

Comment: all integers? are you sure?

Comment: yes, that is what the question says

Comment: perhaps, the question has been written wrong then and means all positive integers.

Comment: Maybe that “for all integers n” $(1-{\sqrt 5})^n$ can be expressed in that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Base Step: $$For\ n=1,\ {{\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right)}^{1}}=a-b\sqrt{5},\ with\ a=1\,and\ b=1$$
2-Inductive step: Assume that ${{\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right)}^{n}}=a-b\sqrt{5},\ Consider\ {{\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right)}^{n+1}}$

$\begin{align}
  & {{\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right)}^{n+1}}=\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right){{\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right)}^{n}} \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ =\left( 1-\sqrt{5} \right)\left( a-\sqrt{5}b \right) \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ =a-a\sqrt{5}+5b-b\sqrt{5} \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ =\left( a+5b \right)-\left( a+b \right)\sqrt{5} \\ 
\end{align}$

So the inductive case holds. Now by induction we see that the assumption is true.

Comment: Last step is uncorrect, it should be $\left( a+\color{red}{5}b \right)-\left( a+b \right)\sqrt{5}$

Comment: thanks for correction

Answer (score 0):

For a **direct proof** let use binomial theorem for $(1-{\sqrt 5})^n$ that is

$$(x+y)^n = {n \choose 0}x^n y^0 + {n \choose 1}x^{n-1}y^1 + {n \choose 2}x^{n-2}y^2 + \cdots + {n \choose n-1}x^1 y^{n-1} + {n \choose n}x^0 y^n$$

By **induction** let consider

- base case: for $n=1\implies (1-{\sqrt 5})^1=1-\sqrt 5$
- induction step: assume that $(1-{\sqrt 5})^n=a-b{\sqrt 5}$ is true then

$$(1-{\sqrt 5})^{n+1}=(1-{\sqrt 5})^n(1-{\sqrt 5})\stackrel{I.H.}=(a-b{\sqrt 5})(1-{\sqrt 5})=\\=a-a\sqrt 5-b\sqrt 5+5b=a+5b-(a+b)\sqrt 5$$

that is

$$(1-{\sqrt 5})^{n+1}=a+5b-(a+b)\sqrt 5$$

Comment: i understand the binomial theorem, but sorry but my knowledge of proof by induction is that good yet so could you give the next step which i might be able to go from.

Comment: You don’t need induction, simply note that x=1, binomial coefficients are integers and $(\sqrt 5)^k$ is an integer for k even and is in the form $b_k(\sqrt 5)^k$ for k odd thus we can collect all terms in the given form.

Comment: the question says i have to prove it through induction

Comment: If you want to prove by induction simply consider the base case for n=1 which is trivial then for induction step assume that $(1-{\sqrt 5})^n=a-b{\sqrt 5}$ and then consider $(1-{\sqrt 5})^{n+1}=(1-{\sqrt 5})^n(1-{\sqrt 5})=(a-b{\sqrt 5})(1-{\sqrt 5})$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $x^{n+1} = x^n\cdot x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;(1-\sqrt{5})(a-b\sqrt{5})=a+5b-(a+b)\sqrt{5}\,$.